# pdfcolorstack error

Tags: errors, pdftex, color

whenever I'm trying to compile LaTeX using TeXmaker, my document provides the following error:

> pdfTeX error (\pdfcolorstack): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0).\set@color ->\pdfcolorstack@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color }\aftergroup... \color{black}"

I could not find a solution for this, as people with a similar error message tried to change colors, but I'm just looking to get rid of this error message, but cannot make a sense out of it. The .tex-file is otherwise working fine, and I can build the PDF with no problem whatsoever, but this error message is bugging me.

What do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please consider providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in order for people to be able to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: you seem to be using latex not pdflatex but forcing pdflatex color options. How are you loading color, and calling latex?

Answer (score 0):

make sur that you are compiling using pdflatex not latex
[image: pdflatex]